# Upload list of binary images using Dio package flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  @override
  Future createVisaFirstStep(
      String departureDate,
      String returnDate,
      int visaType,
      int destinationCountryId,
      int entryCountry,
      List documents) async {
List<Stream<List<int>>> streams = [];
  for (File file in documents) {
    streams.add(Stream.fromFuture(file.readAsBytes()));
  }
    final formData = FormData.fromMap({
      'DepartureDate': departureDate,
      'ReturnDate': returnDate,
      'VisaType': visaType,
      'DestinationCountryId': destinationCountryId,
      'EntryCountry': entryCountry,
      'Documents': streams
    });
    Response response = await refDio.post(
      EndPoints.visaFirstStep,
      data: formData,
    );

    if (response.statusCode != null &&
        response.statusCode! >= 200 &&
        response.statusCode! <= 299) {
      return response.data['data'];
    } else {
      return Future.error('Error ${response.statusCode}');
    }
  }
```

Using Dio package I am trying to send multipart data. List of documents should be binary data. But I am getting an error that E/flutter (10011): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
My list of documents is not null (it is list of Files (images)).